# Delete WAL archive files

Tags: postgresql, backup, postgresql-12, write-ahead-logging

I have around 200Gb of **WAL archives**. Can I just delete them all without considering any database restoration? I am just asking whether it is safe to delete them all or at least 50% of them.

I read a book that one must issue `pg_basebackup` and then delete WAL archives that are older than the "**.backup**" file. But, the postgres manual says that `pg_basebackup` is for cluster backup. My database is not running on cluster mode. So, is `pg_basebackup` still relevant for me ? If not, how do I do backup ? I want to implement PITR and may be need something like base backup.

I am using Postgres 12.

Thanks

Comment: Are you talking about archived WAL segments (archived through the `archive_command`)  or just WAL segments in the `pg_wal` directory?

Comment: Postgres' "cluster" refers to an installation on a particular server, an instance, so `pg_basebackup` is what you need.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name . I am talking about archived WAL segments. The archived WAL is located on a mounted drive, so they are separated from the main server.

Comment: @mustaccio
yes. thank you. how about deleting archived wal files from the archived directory ?

Answer (score 0):

A PostgreSQL cluster is just another word for a PostgreSQL instance, so yes, you are running a cluster. Run a base backup, then you can delete all archived WALs older than the starting checkpoint of the backup if you don't need to restore from any older base backup.

Comment: How about deleting them straight away without doing basebackup ? I know its not recommended, but I just want to do it. I don't have anymore spaces left

Comment: Sure, no problem, except that you have no more backup...

Comment: But what if I do this scenario : delete all archived at first then leave it for a couple of hours (hopefully nothing happens) so that the archived WAL files formed again. After that issue `pg_basebackup`. With this, i will have a just a few archived files. Can I just do this scenario ? Many thanks @LaurenzAlbe

Comment: You don't have to wait. Perform a base backup **immediately** after deleting the archives.